SQLAlchemy SQLLite Unit Test Table missing
I've got the issue, that the SQLLite DB seems to forget all my tables when trying to write an entity while running my Unit Tests.
My setup looks as follows:
class TestBookingApi(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.engine = create_engine("sqlite:///", echo=True, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False})
    Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
    self.patch_db_session = patch('util.util.get_db_session', return_value=Session(self.engine))
    self.patch_db_session.start()


def tearDown(self):
    Base.metadata.drop_all(self.engine)

    self.patch_db_session.stop()


def test_create_booking(self):
    # when
    booking = setup_booking()

    # then
    with Client(app) as client:
        result = client.http.post(
            "/api/bookings",
            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body=booking.json()
        )

        # expect
        assert result.status_code == HTTPStatus.CREATED
        body = result.json_body
        api_booking = Booking(**body)
        assert api_booking.name == booking.name
        assert len(api_booking.hardware) == 2

def test_create_booking(self):
    # when
    booking = setup_booking()

    # then
    with Client(app) as client:
        result = client.http.post(
            "/api/bookings",
            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body=booking.json()
        )

        # expect
        assert result.status_code == HTTPStatus.CREATED
        body = result.json_body
        api_booking = Booking(**body)
        assert api_booking.name == booking.name
        assert len(api_booking.hardware) == 2

The controller that writes into the db:
def create_booking():
    request = api.current_request
    try:
        json_body = request.json_body
        request_booking = parse_model(BookingRequest, json_body)

        hardware = []
        for hardware_id in request_booking.hardware_ids:
            request_hardware = get_hardware(hardware_id)
            hardware.append(request_hardware)

        db_booking = convert_to_db_booking(request_booking, hardware)
        bookings_db.create_booking(db_booking)

        return Response(
            status_code=HTTPStatus.CREATED,
            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body=db_booking.json()
        )
    except (ValidationError, ValueError) as e:
        raise BadRequestError(str(e))

When i'm debugging now and set a debug point on bookings_db.create_booking(db_booking), every property on the db_booking entity has the following error:
[SQL: SELECT bookings.id AS bookings_id, bookings.name AS bookings_name, bookings.customer_id AS bookings_customer_id, bookings.booking_start AS bookings_booking_start, bookings.booking_end AS bookings_booking_end, bookings.created_at AS bookings_created_at, bookings.updated_at AS bookings_updated_at 
FROM bookings 
WHERE bookings.id = ?]


Anyone here with a clue what's the issue here? 

